# Get cropped image in react?

Tags: reactjs

How to get cropped image through "react-easy-crop" without download, only get and post to backend as image not canvas in React.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olINM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then this example should solve your problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/q8q1mnr01w

Comment: Great answer!

What if want to show the image using raw data like crop, zoom,rotation,cropedAre?